# whitespace between tabs list and tabs content

Tags: html, jquery, css, tabs

I design the vertical tab using CSS and jQuery. I have two main `div`:

- `.tabs` with a list of tabs name
- `.tab_container` with the content of each tab.

But there is a whitespace between them:

[image: 1]

```js
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).show();

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");

  /*$(".tabs").css("margin-top", function(){ 
     return ($(".tab_container").outerHeight() - $(".tabs").outerHeight() ) / 2;
  });*/
});
$(".tab_container").css("min-height", function() {
  return $(".tabs").outerHeight() + 50;
});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).show();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.tabs_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

ul.tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

ul.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  border-left: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.tabs li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: unset;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.tab_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 84%;
  min-width: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  display: none;
}

.tab_container__contents {}

.tab_container__meta {
  width: 20%;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_wrapper">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
    <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>
    <li rel="tab5">Tab 5</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet brisket t-bone salami prosciutto beef biltong kevin tenderloin bresaola sirloin turducken pork leberkas tongue capicola. T-bone fatback biltong doner capicola. Boudin turducken t-bone ham hock, ball tip ribeye meatball
        bresaola kevin turkey drumstick. Ham hock strip steak chicken jerky bacon sausage tail tri-tip sirloin ham venison rump chuck pork leberkas. Capicola bacon shoulder leberkas ham bresaola meatloaf beef corned beef venison pastrami t-bone pork chop
        tail. Biltong capicola pork fatback, short loin sirloin filet mignon jerky pig ribeye ground round tenderloin hamburger. Shoulder ham short loin rump, strip steak kielbasa tri-tip shank leberkas.</p>
      <p>Pork filet mignon rump salami, tri-tip ham hock turducken meatball spare ribs tail shoulder pork belly sirloin. Sirloin fatback bresaola, biltong brisket pancetta tenderloin tri-tip. Ground round salami shank, chicken pig sausage shankle. Frankfurter
        andouille jowl pastrami ribeye. Leberkas short loin beef turkey pancetta jowl. T-bone sirloin pork belly jowl, bacon beef ribs ground round tongue.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab1 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
      <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab2 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
      <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab3 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
      <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab4 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab5">Tab 5</h3>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 5 content</h2>
      <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

How do can I fix this problem?

Comment: It is the unaccounted 1% width between `.tabs` and `.tab_container`

Answer (score 1):

The "white space" is due to the 20px of padding of `.tab_content` in your CSS:

```
.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

If you remove it, the "white space" will disappear:

```js
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).show();

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");

  /*$(".tabs").css("margin-top", function(){ 
     return ($(".tab_container").outerHeight() - $(".tabs").outerHeight() ) / 2;
  });*/
});
$(".tab_container").css("min-height", function() {
  return $(".tabs").outerHeight() + 50;
});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).show();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.tabs_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

ul.tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

ul.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  border-left: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.tabs li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: unset;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.tab_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 84%;
  min-width: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.tab_content {
  /* padding: 20px; */
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  display: none;
}

.tab_container__contents {}

.tab_container__meta {
  width: 20%;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_wrapper">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
    <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>
    <li rel="tab5">Tab 5</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet brisket t-bone salami prosciutto beef biltong kevin tenderloin bresaola sirloin turducken pork leberkas tongue capicola. T-bone fatback biltong doner capicola. Boudin turducken t-bone ham hock, ball tip ribeye meatball
        bresaola kevin turkey drumstick. Ham hock strip steak chicken jerky bacon sausage tail tri-tip sirloin ham venison rump chuck pork leberkas. Capicola bacon shoulder leberkas ham bresaola meatloaf beef corned beef venison pastrami t-bone pork chop
        tail. Biltong capicola pork fatback, short loin sirloin filet mignon jerky pig ribeye ground round tenderloin hamburger. Shoulder ham short loin rump, strip steak kielbasa tri-tip shank leberkas.</p>
      <p>Pork filet mignon rump salami, tri-tip ham hock turducken meatball spare ribs tail shoulder pork belly sirloin. Sirloin fatback bresaola, biltong brisket pancetta tenderloin tri-tip. Ground round salami shank, chicken pig sausage shankle. Frankfurter
        andouille jowl pastrami ribeye. Leberkas short loin beef turkey pancetta jowl. T-bone sirloin pork belly jowl, bacon beef ribs ground round tongue.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab1 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
      <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab2 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
      <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab3 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
      <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab4 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab5">Tab 5</h3>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 5 content</h2>
      <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Comment: the width of `.tabs` is: `15%` and width of `tab_container` is: `84%`. and equal = `99%`. I need to change `84% to 85%`. if so, your code doesn't work and I see `whitespace` again. demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6znm31dw/

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace between the two elements is caused by the line break in your HTML. Line breaks between inline elements are transformed into a single white space.

```js
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).show();

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");

  /*$(".tabs").css("margin-top", function(){ 
     return ($(".tab_container").outerHeight() - $(".tabs").outerHeight() ) / 2;
  });*/
});
$(".tab_container").css("min-height", function() {
  return $(".tabs").outerHeight() + 50;
});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).show();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.tabs_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

ul.tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15%;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

ul.tabs li {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  border-left: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.tabs li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: unset;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.tab_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 84%;
  min-width: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ecf1f3;
  display: none;
}

.tab_container__contents {}

.tab_container__meta {
  width: 20%;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs_wrapper">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
    <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
    <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
    <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>
    <li rel="tab5">Tab 5</li>
  </ul><div class="tab_container"> <!-- EDIT: moved these to the same line to remove whitespace -->
    <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet brisket t-bone salami prosciutto beef biltong kevin tenderloin bresaola sirloin turducken pork leberkas tongue capicola. T-bone fatback biltong doner capicola. Boudin turducken t-bone ham hock, ball tip ribeye meatball
        bresaola kevin turkey drumstick. Ham hock strip steak chicken jerky bacon sausage tail tri-tip sirloin ham venison rump chuck pork leberkas. Capicola bacon shoulder leberkas ham bresaola meatloaf beef corned beef venison pastrami t-bone pork chop
        tail. Biltong capicola pork fatback, short loin sirloin filet mignon jerky pig ribeye ground round tenderloin hamburger. Shoulder ham short loin rump, strip steak kielbasa tri-tip shank leberkas.</p>
      <p>Pork filet mignon rump salami, tri-tip ham hock turducken meatball spare ribs tail shoulder pork belly sirloin. Sirloin fatback bresaola, biltong brisket pancetta tenderloin tri-tip. Ground round salami shank, chicken pig sausage shankle. Frankfurter
        andouille jowl pastrami ribeye. Leberkas short loin beef turkey pancetta jowl. T-bone sirloin pork belly jowl, bacon beef ribs ground round tongue.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab1 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
      <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab2 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
      <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab3 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
      <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- #tab4 -->
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab5">Tab 5</h3>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
      <h2>Tab 5 content</h2>
      <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but when I need to beautify code, I see the `whitespace` again.

Comment: @CodeCover you also could close the gap forcefully by using `margin-left: -4px` on `.tab_container`